# View Source Button - Not working anymore

Tags: view-source

Why does the primitive method no longer work on this page (in Chrome)?

I use the same functionality on my website and it has stopped working as well.

https://css-tricks.com/examples/ViewSourceButton/#

Here is the line:

```
 <a class="button" onClick='window.location="view-source:" + window.location.href'>Primitive View Source</a>
```